# Using SVGs as React Components in a Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, create-react-app

Hey all I'm trying to figure out **how to set/render SVGs as React components in a JavaScript Map**. I'm wanting to do this because *I'd like to be able to import the SVGs once but then be able to change the color of them throughout my application through their props* i.e `<Logo fill={color} />`

I'm pretty new to React so please let me know what if there is a better way to tackle this than how I'm doing it. Thanks!

```js
// LogoMap.js

import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "assets/MyLogo.svg";

const LogoMap = new Map();

LogoMap.set("1", Logo);
// ... Setting more items

export { LogoMap }
```

```js
import { LogoMap } from "data/LogoMap";

function MyComponent() {
    const Logo_One = LogoMap.get("1")

    return (
        // How do I render Logo_One? Or what is a better way to go about this?
        // I've tried doing <Logo_One /> but I get the error:
        // "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."
        <Logo_One fill="blue">
    );
}
```

Comment: I ended up solving this by using this package NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-inlinesvg. So instead of creating a map of ID --> React component, I did a map of ID --> Image and just used that image src url in the Inline SVG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (OP) ended up solving this by using this package NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-inlinesvg.

So instead of creating a map of ID --> React Component, I did a map of ID --> Image Source(string) and just used that image src url in the Inline SVG.

Here is the finished code of what I ended up doing

```js
// LogoMap.js

import MyLogo from "assets/MyLogo.svg";

const LogoMap = new Map();

LogoMap.set("1", MyLogo);
// ... Setting more items

export { LogoMap }
```

```js
import { LogoMap } from "data/LogoMap";

function MyComponent() {
    const LogoOne = LogoMap.get("1")

    return (
        <Svg src={LogoOne} fill="blue" />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using the right methods for the built in map.

```
LogoMap.set('1', Logo);
```

retrieving

```
LogoMap.get('1')
```

A more react-y way to do it would be creating a component that wraps the Map, so that you don't need to expose it. In the code that I write, I just use an object instead of the Map data structure

```
const icons = {
  "1": Logo1,
  ....
}
const MyIcon = props => {
  const icon = map.get(props.name) // or icons[props.name];

  return <icon fill={props.fill} {...props} />
}
```

Comment: Ah on setting/retrieving that was my bad, I was trying to change some of the variable names to anonymize the code and looks like I deleted too much. I've updated the code to be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using and literal object for this case, but that's not the problem here.

I recommend you save your "Logo" like this:

```
LogoMap("1", (props) => <Logo {...props}/>);
```

then

```
import { LogoMap } from "data/LogoMap";

function MyComponent() {
    const LogoOne = myMap.get("1")

    return 
        <LogoOne fill="blue">
    );
}
```

I think that should work!
I hope i have been able to help you